# Is there a more elegant way to count words and assign that count to variables?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

/root/xiotech status > xiostatus.tmp
SyncCount=$(grep -c Sync xiostatus.tmp)
PauseCount=$(grep -c paused xiostatus.tmp)
CopyingCount=$(grep -c Copying xiostatus.tmp)

if [ "$SyncCount" -eq "11" ]
then echo All 11 mirrors are in sync.

else echo $PauseCount mirrors are paused and $CopyingCount mirrors are syncing.
fi

rm -f xiostatus.tmp
```

Is there a more elegant way to count and "variable-ize" those counts using something like awk?  In this case the file is tiny so it's not a big deal, but if the file were 900mb, it would take a lot of extra cycles to go through it 3 times...

Comment: Can more than one keyword occur on a line? Can the same keyword occur multiple times in one line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`awk` can replace the entire script pretty easily:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/Sync/ {SyncCount++}
/paused/ {PauseCount++}
/Copying/ {CopyingCount++}

END {
    if(SyncCount == 11)
        print "All 11 mirrors are in sync."
    else
        print (+PauseCount) " mirrors are paused and " (+CopyingCount) " mirrors are syncing."
}
```

The `(+var)` is to force `awk` to treat the variable as a number (so it will output `0` if the variable was unset). You can also use a `BEGIN` block to set all the variables to `0` initially:

```
BEGIN {
    SyncCount = PauseCount = CopyingCount = 0
}
```

---

Stick that in a file and run `awk -f /path/to/the/script.awk xiostatus.tmp`. If you don't need the temporary file, you can even do `/root/xiotech status | awk -f /path/to/the/script.awk`.

If you set the execution bit on the `awk` script, you can call it as a standalone executable: `/path/to/the/script.awk xiostatus.tmp`, or `/root/xiotech status | /path/to/the/script.awk`.

Comment: Works if there is only one instance of the search strings per line.

Comment: @Arcege True, I assumed. I don't know if there's a clean way to match the same pattern multiple times per line; I think most people do ugly `match()`/`substr()` trickery

Comment: There is only one per line. Is there a way to assign 0 to values that are not returned?  the print won't print anything if the value is null, I guess....

Comment: @LVLAaron You can use a `BEGIN` block; I added it to the answer

Comment: You don't need to initialize the vars in `BEGIN` if you force them to print as *numbers* and not as (default) *strings* — just put a **plus sign** in front of each var and wrap it in brackets (it misbehaves badly with `print`  if you don't use the brackets) — `awk 'END{neg=-1; pos=+1; printf "%d %d %d", +neg, +pos, +uninit; print " |",  (+neg), (+pos), (+uninit)}' /dev/null` — outputs: `-1 1 0 | -1 1 0`

Comment: *BUG alert! or how NOT to use `+var` and the SAFE way to use it*. A further note to my previous comment ― Using GNU Awk 3.1.6, the `print` statement behaves oddly when using the leading `+`. It prints as expected when using **comma** `,` seperators, but does not print the strings preceding each instance of  `+var` when you don't use commas... The way it works properly is to wrap the +var in **brackets** as (+var) — `print  (+neg) " abc " (+pos) " def " (+uninit)`, or use comma seperators. `printf` does not have this issue, and it works fine whether you use brackets or not.

Comment: @Peter.O Nice. I left it as `print` and used the parentheses

Comment: PS. It was bugging me, but is *not* a bug. It is a **syntax** issue — eg. `pos=1; print +pos +pos` outputs `2`  — In this example the usage priority of the second `+` is obviously as an *addition* operator. It seems that strings are considered to be numbers when followed by a `+`. They have a numeric value of `0` when they are *non-numeric*, hence `"abc" +pos` == *0+1* == *1* — but when the string resolves to a number, it is considered as such.. `" 3 " +pos` == *3+1* == *4* —   even  `" 3xxxx " +pos` == *3+1* == *4*

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: added `awk` shebang and a sentence explaining how to get advantage of it.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: In my testing, I've found that rather than using the *"range"* test `/Sync/`, and, instead, by putting the tests in the curly-bracketed main execution block,like this: `{ if( match($0,"Sync") ) {SyncCount[1]++}; if( match($0, ... }`, the script runs *twice* as fast... (which is still  slower than Arcege's grep method.

Answer (score 4):

For those who want to count **all** instances, here is an awk version which will count **multiple** *non-overlapping* instances when there is more than one on the same line

*UPDATE:* I have now included another method which uses `split(...`. It is  *much* faster than the `match( substr(...` method which is now listed below the faster one. 
The `split(...` method is more than 4 times faster than the  other... (tested on 87 files for a total of 407,612 lines.
For further comparison, *Michael Mrozek's* method, using `/Sync/` range-selection (which counts *lines* containg each pattern vs. counting *all* instances of the pattern) is twice as fast as this new method (for the same data).

Another fringe(?) benefit of this faster `split(methos)` is that it is quite tolerant to invalid UTF-8 chars in the file (so long as they are not in the delimiter pattern)... The **delimiters** are themselves the actual string patterns being counted...  Several of my test files had invalid UTF-8 in them, and it took me quite a while to discover why I got different results from the two methods.
Once the problem files were re-encoded to valid UTF-8, both methods produce identical results.

Here is the new faster method (4+ times faster)... using `split(...`

```
#!/bin/bash
pat='xx|yy|zz'
awk -v vpat="$pat" 'BEGIN { 
  split(vpat, pat, "|"); for(i in pat) pz++ 
} 
{ if (NF) { for( p in pat ) { ct[p]+=(split( $0, A, pat[p] ) -1) }}
}
END { print " count   pattern"
      for (p=1; p<=pz; p++) { printf "%6d   %s\n", +ct[p], pat[p] } 
}' file
```

---

Here is the Slower method.  using `match( substr(...`

```
#!/bin/bash
# Count occurrences of multiple non-overlapping string patterns
awk 'BEGIN {
  pattern[1]="xx"
  pattern[2]="yy"
  pattern[3]="zz"
}
{ for( p in pattern ) {
    LHB=0; RSTART=RLENGTH=1
    while( match( substr( $0, LHB+=(RSTART+RLENGTH-1)), pattern[p] )){
      count[p]++ 
    }
  }
} END {
  print "occurs  pattern"
  for (p in pattern) {
    printf "%6d  %s\n", +count[p], pattern[p] 
  } 
}' file
```

Here is the input file

```
xx xx  xx
xx             yy           xx
```

The output is as follows:

```
occurs  pattern
     5  xx
     1  yy
     0  zz
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
eval `/root/xiotech status | grep -Eo 'Sync|paused|Copying' | sort | uniq -c | 
    awk '{print "count_" $2 "=" $1}'`
if [ "$count_Sync" -eq 11 ]; then
    echo All 11 mirrors are in sync.
else
    echo $count_paused mirrors are paused and $count_Copying mirrors are syncing.
fi
```

The `grep -Eo` allows for searching multiple patterns (separated by "|") and returns only the string that matched.  The `sort | uniq -c` shows the count of the words found.  The awk script formats new shell commands to create variables starting with "count_".  And finally, the `eval` will take the created shell commands and evaluate them within the shell.

Comment: This doesn't work. It adds everything up to 11 every time no matter what the lines are.

Comment: @LVLAaron Really? It works for me, although it has the same problem my answer had (empty strings instead of 0s if the search term doesn't appear)

Comment: @Arcege: +1 It is lightning fast! at 5-6 times faster than the closest contender (Michaek Mrozek's, which I believe can be tweaked to double its speed) ... It just needs some other method of handling patterns which aren't found...  There is just one thing about it which prevents this from being general purposs.. It matches the **first** pattern it finds and then continues the search *after* that match.. This works for the specs of the question, but it means that because of an overlapping **"are"**, `"beware|will|miss|are"` and other such overlapping patterns